# AWS EC2 Ubuntu Instance tightvncserver with RealVNC on Win11Home

Tags: vnc, amazon-ec2

I've followed the tutorial step by step
[Ubuntu VNC on AWS EC2](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/ubuntu-desktop-aws#1-overview)

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-17-214:~$ uname -a
Linux ip-172-31-17-214 6.2.0-1015-aws #15~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct  6 21:37:24 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
ubuntu@ip-172-31-17-214:~$ cat ~/.vnc/xstartup
#!/bin/sh

export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey

vncconfig -iconic &
gnome-panel &
gnome-settings-daemon &
metacity &
nautilus &
gnome-terminal &
#gnome-session &
ubuntu@ip-172-31-17-214:~$ vncserver :1

New 'X' desktop is ip-172-31-17-214:1

Starting applications specified in /home/ubuntu/.vnc/xstartup
Log file is /home/ubuntu/.vnc/ip-172-31-17-214:1.log
```

But got a grey screen...

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-17-214:~$ tail -f /home/ubuntu/.vnc/ip-172-31-17-214:1.log
07/11/23 01:25:03 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 21
07/11/23 01:25:03 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 15
07/11/23 01:25:03 Using zlib encoding for client 207.6.201.205
07/11/23 01:25:03 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -314
07/11/23 01:25:03 Enabling full-color cursor updates for client 207.6.201.205
07/11/23 01:25:03 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -223
07/11/23 01:25:03 Pixel format for client 207.6.201.205:
07/11/23 01:25:03   32 bpp, depth 24, little endian
07/11/23 01:25:03   true colour: max r 255 g 255 b 255, shift r 16 g 8 b 0
07/11/23 01:25:03   no translation needed
```

Any suggestions?